# Difference between IPC and CPI

Tags: computer-science

Are IPC and CPI simply inverses of each other? Or is it not that simple?

From what I've read they are really similar and it's hard to see whether they are simply inverses of each other or if they have any real differences.

EDIT: I'm sorry I didn't clarify, but yes, I mean instructions-per-cycle and cycles-per instruction.

EDIT2: I think I found the answer. They are not simply inverses, they are multiplicative inverses which are a bit different than normal inverses. Thanks for the help.

Comment: **`IPC`** and **`CPI`** would be the reciprocal of each other, as in **Instructions Per Cycle** and **Cycles Per Instruction**.

Comment: Reciprocal means that they are simply inverses if I understand correctly? Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: @user2295594 Shirt answer is YES. For more info look at pages 13-17 of [this presentation](http://www.dauniv.ac.in/downloads/CArch_PPTs/CompArchCh01L6techtrendBenchmarks.pdf).

Comment: @user2295594 I don't know what you think a "normal inverse" is - multiplicative *is* normal inverse.

Answer (score 4):

The number of instructions per clock cycle or,

> IPC = Number of instructions executed while running a program / 
>   number of clock cycles required to execute the program

The Number of clock cycles required to execute each instruction,

> CPI = The number of clock cycles required to execute the program / number of instructions executed in running the program

Both metrics give the same information & the choice of which one to use is **generally** made based on which of the values is greater than the number 1

For systems that can execute more than one instruction per cycle, the number of instructions executed per cycle, or IPC often used instead of CPI

Say there is a loop with 80 instruction executed 42 times and a total of 10,000 cycles were taken  to execute the program, so ,

the total executed instructions = 80 x 42 = 3360

- CPI = 10000/3360 = 2.97
- IPC = 3360/10000 = 0.33

[modern (intel)superscalar CPUs retire 4 instruction per cycle (IPC);
so ideal CPI for modern processors = 1/4 = 0.25](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-insights-to-intel-hyper-threading-technology) .
So by comparing ideal and actual , you can know that your code might be stalling & is unable to harness the computing resources within the Processor!

Comment: Are there systems that can execute more than one instruction per cycle? If not, IPC feels rather pointless. Counting cycles per instruction would make more sense.